# Serializing std::map c++

Tags: c++, stdmap, midl

I have an object of **std::map** in my VC++ application. The format of the map is as follows:
`map<CString, map<CString, CSimpleArray<CString>>> x;`

I want to pass this object to  server through a RPC call. So, I am using MIDL for creating the client and server stubs for RPC calls.

But, MIDL does not support higher level datatypes. So, is there any way I can pass this object to the server using MIDL?
Or, how can I serialize it to basic data types, so that I can pass them to the server using MIDL?

I am using VS2015 for the development purpose.

Comment: Think about using Googles Protocol Buffers. They provide a nice way to provide Data in a serialized manner.

Comment: Thanks @Nidhoegger. I'll surely have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest serializing this complex structure to XML or JSON and pass it as a string.

Comment: Easy to parse and control data integrity.

Comment: The 1990s called and they want their misunderstood fad back ^_^ XML is _so_ bloated and it is **not** "easy to parse". There are much better alternatives widely used today.

Comment: You can use JSON if you like it. You can even use ASN.1 encoded using BER to do that. There are many formats you can use, but XML is so easy to implement.

Comment: I didn't say anything about JSON, though that would already be a heck of a lot easier to parse than XML.

Comment: "_XML combines the efficiency of text files with the readability of binary files_"